# How to display a specific row at the top while selecting multiple rows in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table as activities with column id,title,content,posted_date and I want to fetch record like the row would be displayed at the top of which I have specified the id and there after all the rows should be displayed. I have written the following query but It's throwing an error.

```
SELECT * FROM `activities` limit 0,4 put top WHERE id = 4
```

Comment: Strictly speaking, the rows selected in a relational database are an UNORDERED SET.  The #/rows match the selected criteria: NOTHING ELSE.  The "limit" clause (like "top N" in SQL server) are extensions ... and completely at odds with how you're SUPPOSED to think about relational databases. I would discourage using them in any "production code".

Comment: Limit 0,4 is same as limit 4 isn't it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can order by `id=4` ...

Add `, posted_date asc` to order the rest or ommit if you don't care the order of the rest..

```
   select
          *
   from 
         activities
   order by  
        id=4 desc,
        posted_date asc 
        limit 4
```

Comment: can we use order by on posted_date

Comment: Yeah just change to ` id=4, posted_date asc limit 4`

Comment: actually I want a specific row then I want to filter the rest of the rows based on posted_date column

Answer (score 0):

You can use conditional order by clause

```
SELECT *
FROM `activities`
ORDER BY id = 4 DESC
LIMIT 0,4
```

Or

```
SELECT *
FROM `activities`
ORDER BY CASE WHEN id = 4 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END DESC
LIMIT 0,4
```

Comment: can we use filter here based on different column instead of id ?

Comment: @AbhayjeetSingh Can you please specify which filter you want to use to sort rows, By the way you can use

Comment: Problem statement: There are some links when a user clicks on any link the details would be displayed of each link but the link would be displayed at the top on which the user had clicked

Comment: links are attached with id column

Comment: @AbhayjeetSingh Its still unclear can you please update your question with related details you have